# Passing dates as parameters in a Pentaho SFTP step

Tags: sftp, pentaho

How can I pass the current date formatted as YYYYMMDD to a SFTP file transfer in a Pentaho Kettle Job?
I have the below job running correctly in Pentaho CE
It connects to an SFTP and pulls the zip file with the date 20150924
I want this to be dynamic for automation, always pulling the current date on each run.

[image]

I made the below transformation, it pulls the current date as ‘Tdate’
How do I use my Tdate from the transformation as a parameter  (or another way) in my job. 
[image]

I’ve tried a few variants but just haven’t got this to link up right / used the right steps/code
Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you see the dollar sign ($) beside the file name in the 'Wildcard' field? That means you can use a variable for that field. Set a parameter in the job (probably called TDATE) and use the `Set variables` step in your transform (instead of `Copy rows to result`) to initialize the value prior to the `Get a file with SFTP` step.

PS, you could also use a `JavaScript` step to set the variable, but I prefer not to break the visual paradigm.

Comment: This led to the result; A few other steps were needed: In the transformation: select the resulting date value as a string in a step; and then add the .zip in a calculation step. The transformation creating the parameter ${TDATE} was added as a step to the GetDate Job. (Agree + a Javascript statement would have been a lot easier, at least I have a pretty visualization of the flow now though)

Comment: I prefer to avoid scripting if possible. IMO the visual flow is important to maintainability.